# Services, applications do not work - Windows 10

Tags: windows, ssd, cmd.exe

I had a Windows 10 - operated laptop. I recently switched to Windows 8.1, because Windows 10 has a lot of problems.

As in the title, services do not work (obviously not all of them), and I am fed up.

- StopWindows10 Updates (I am not sure of the name, but I was unable to update Windows. All it said was: "Error encountered with Settings. Please reopen settings later." I am not sure of what the error message really was, but something similar to it.
- CHKDSK, DISM, Disk Defragment doesn't work. Either I end up getting error messages, or the process would happen for an infinite amount of time, if I just let it run. I cannot repair my OS, since DISM does not work at all.
- I have a 64-bit operating system, so is it going to be really beneficial for me to download a 32-bit operating system and go along with it?
- I keep receiving messages that .dll files are not installed whenever I install applications. Why? I do have a fast internet, the downloading file is never disrupted, but still, it just has to get that message on my screen.
- Problem encountered, I solve the problem, another one pops up. Is this how unstable Windows 10 is? The older versions of Windows - like Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 were way better than Windows 10.
- Programs crash, slow start-up, slow execution of files, even though I have an SSD with 16gb RAM. I guess that **IS** definitely enough for a Windows 10 PC to work.
- I have tried installing Windows 10 in the past, legacy booting, UEFI booting, but none of them really works. It just ends up the way like how it always, just like how I mentioned above.

I have switched to Windows 8.1 for now, but if I have to upgrade to Windows 10 in the future, I really don't wanna end up struggling this hard.

Thanks.

EDIT: The stopwindows10 updates application that I mentioned above, is a third-party app, but neither do I really know how I came by it, nor am I aware of when it installed itself. Also, a service runs known as StopWindows10 Updates, but I cannot disable the service, even though I am an admin. All I receive is "Access Denied."

Comment: "StopWindows10 Updates" sounds like third-party software you installed.  Please [edit] your question to clarify this particular point.  You also need to provide any error messages.  We are not familiar with your issue.

Comment: Windows 10 is rock-solid in most cases. You might have installed some problematic programs (both in Windows 10 & 8.1), or you might be having hardware problems. Look in the Event Viewer for useful error messages.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, it is. Tried deleting the StopWindows10 Updates thing (By the way, I didn't install it on purpose, but maybe installed itself while I installed some program), but seems like it's verified by some random company, but not by Microsoft. Will add the info above.

Comment: @harrymc, I can definitely understand that, but I have mentioned above saying that I have installed Windows 8.1, and I don't have any error messages with me, nor do I remember any. And, I have no problems with windows 8.1, but it's windows 10 that causes problems.

Comment: Programs like StopWindows10Updates are only installed when they are specifically and purposely downloaded. I assume the program is actually called **stopupdates10** appears to be extremely low quality software that has lots of bugs that likely permanently made irreversible changes to Windows 10 (despite saying they were) the type of program that requires you to perform a complete reinstall of Windows.  Seriously, reinstalling Windows is your best solution

Comment: Well, I am not aware of that, but I am pretty sure I haven't downloaded it on purpose. I update frequently (Kinda obsessed with that), so there is no way I would install such an application to **stop** my updates. And, I currently don't have Windows 10 with me, so there is basically nothing I can do anything. Plus, I think I may get an additional performance boost, so I am satisfied. Really require Microsoft to release Windows 11. Jeez.

Comment: I still don’t understand your question.  It should be a simple matter of installing all Windows 8.1 updates then upgrading to Windows 10.  The amount of time to update Windows 8.1 will be a few hours due to the number of patches that have to be installed.  Since it’s a fresh, clean, install the upgrade to Windows 10 should be extremely short.  Just download the Media Creation Tool from Microsoft

Comment: I usually do a fresh, clean install of Windows 10 (directly), Whenever it came to it, I haven't upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. But I guess there is no use of fussing over it, so thanks.